# Live xpath search in your browser

Tags: search, xpath, plugins

Is there a tool or browser plugin (not sure if Firebug can do this) that will let you open a web page and then using the tool/plugin to search using an xpath query and it will highlight the things on the screen that match your query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firebug and Chrome Web Inspector offers the `$x()` convenience function, which dumps the results of an xpath query to the console (where they can be hovered over to highlight). Not quite what you want though.

And then there's [XPather](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1192), which does a whole lot more.

Comment: xpather seems to do the trick.  I can enter in an xpath and it will show me the matching node/s.  thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately XPather seems to be abandoned and unavailable for current browser versions: "Not available for Firefox 20.0"